# ruby pipes to bash commands

Tags: ruby, bash, pipe

I am creating a ruby wrapper for axel which will issue a HTTP get request to a website directory, parse it for downloadable content, and then pass the full URL off to axel to download one by one sequentially as axel doesnt have this ability. (got the idea from Firefox's "DownThemAll!" plugin.)

My question is, is it possible in ruby to take axels STDOUT response and display it from my ruby wrapper real time or maybe ever x seconds? I know if i used back ticks or the `%w()` method of running the command that I will not see any results from its STDOUT until after axel has completed downloading, but I am wondering if it is at all possible to grab its output while it is running so that I can display its download status from inside my wrapper. (using -a flag on axel for an alternate view so it doesn't scroll the screen.)

Thanks for any information you can inform me with towards this topic.

PS: also if i have to redraw the screen, I don't mind. As in get axels STDOUT every x seconds, clear the screen, and then output the new information from my wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of talking with a friend he pointed me to this which is exactly what I needed.

http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/pty/rdoc/PTY.html